# Javascript - How could I change my regex, ^\d*\.?\d{0,2}$, to allow a comma instead of a decimal point?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using the pattern `^\d*\.?\d{0,2}$` to display currency, e.g. it only allows allows numbers before an optional decimal point and two decimal place after the decimal point.

For localisation purposes, I need to have the option of allowing the use of a comma instead of a decimal point and decimal points instead of commas for numbers in the thousands, e.g. €123.123,00 instead of €123,123.00.

I thought it would be as simple as replacing the `.` in `\.?` with `,` but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `/^\d*,?\d{0,2}$/` works for me

Comment: _doesn't seem to work_ is a very precise problem description. What exactly does not work? What are the samples you test this with?

Comment: `/^\d*(?:(?:,\d{3})*\.?|(?:\.\d{3})*,?)\d{0,2}$/` should work for both the cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following regex seems to be what you really want:

```
^(?:\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?|\d{1,3}(\.\d{3})*(,\d+)?)$
```

## Regex101

**Explanation:**

```
\d{1,3}     match 1 to 3 numbers
(,\d{3})*   followed any amount of ,xxx groups
(\.\d+)?    followed by an optional period and then one or more numbers
```

Explaining the first half of the alternation should be sufficient, because the second half just switches the role of comma and period, as is seen in Europe.

Here is a demo showing this regex in action:

```js
console.log(/^(?:\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?|\d{1,3}(\.\d{3})*(\,\d+)?)$/.test('1'));
console.log(/^(?:\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?|\d{1,3}(\.\d{3})*(\,\d+)?)$/.test('1'));
console.log(/^(?:\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?|\d{1,3}(\.\d{3})*(\,\d+)?)$/.test('12'));
console.log(/^(?:\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?|\d{1,3}(\.\d{3})*(\,\d+)?)$/.test('123'));
console.log(/^(?:\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?|\d{1,3}(\.\d{3})*(\,\d+)?)$/.test('1,234'));
console.log(/^(?:\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?|\d{1,3}(\.\d{3})*(\,\d+)?)$/.test('12,345'));
console.log(/^(?:\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?|\d{1,3}(\.\d{3})*(\,\d+)?)$/.test('123,456'));
console.log(/^(?:\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?|\d{1,3}(\.\d{3})*(\,\d+)?)$/.test('123,456.123'));
console.log(/^(?:\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?|\d{1,3}(\.\d{3})*(\,\d+)?)$/.test('1.3'));
console.log(/^(?:\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?|\d{1,3}(\.\d{3})*(\,\d+)?)$/.test('1.'));
```

Answer (score 0):

`[/.,]` will check if there is a dot OR a comma
without the [ ] you just check if those are afterwards

Answer (score 0):

`^\d*\,?\d{0,2}$` This works fine for me. I tested it with 123,00 on https://regex101.com/.